# Não consigo publicar meu app MEAN na OpenShift

Tags: javascript, git, deploy, openshift, node.js

Eu fiz tudo o que parece certo. Mudei as variáveis locais para `process.env`, mas quando eu dou commit e send recebo esta saída:

```
Pushing to ssh://56bc23fd0c1e667ea00000e3@pontotec-smallservices.rhcloud.com/~/git/pontotec.git/
remote: Stopping NodeJS cartridge        
remote: Thu Feb 11 2016 23:27:28 GMT-0500 (EST): Stopping application 'pontotec' ...        
remote: Thu Feb 11 2016 23:27:29 GMT-0500 (EST): Stopped Node application 'pontotec'        
remote: Stopping MongoDB cartridge        
remote: Saving away previously installed Node modules        
remote: Building git ref 'master', commit e7b5753        
remote: Building NodeJS cartridge        
remote: npm info it worked if it ends with ok        
remote: npm info using npm@1.4.28        
remote: npm info using node@v0.10.35        
remote: npm info preinstall 2des@0.0.0        
remote: npm WARN package.json dependable@0.2.5 No description        
remote: npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 23:27:48        
remote: npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/prerender-node        
remote: npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 23:27:48        
remote: npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sugar        
remote: npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 23:27:48        
remote: npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt        
remote: npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 23:27:48        
remote: npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bwip-js

[.....................blablabla.......................]

remote: ├── dateformat@1.0.2-1.2.3        
remote: ├── eventemitter2@0.4.14        
remote: ├── getobject@0.1.0        
remote: ├── rimraf@2.2.8        
remote: ├── colors@0.6.2        
remote: ├── async@0.1.22        
remote: ├── hooker@0.2.3        
remote: ├── grunt-legacy-util@0.2.0        
remote: ├── exit@0.1.2        
remote: ├── nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.7)        
remote: ├── minimatch@0.2.14 (sigmund@1.0.1, lru-cache@2.7.3)        
remote: ├── glob@3.1.21 (inherits@1.0.2, graceful-fs@1.2.3)        
remote: ├── lodash@0.9.2        
remote: ├── coffee-script@1.3.3        
remote: ├── underscore.string@2.2.1        
remote: ├── iconv-lite@0.2.11        
remote: ├── findup-sync@0.1.3 (glob@3.2.11, lodash@2.4.2)        
remote: ├── js-yaml@2.0.5 (argparse@0.1.16, esprima@1.0.4)        
remote: └── grunt-legacy-log@0.1.3 (grunt-legacy-log-utils@0.1.1, underscore.string@2.3.3, lodash@2.4.2)        
remote: 
remote: mongodb@2.1.7 node_modules/mongodb        
remote: ├── es6-promise@3.0.2        
remote: ├── readable-stream@1.0.31 (isarray@0.0.1, inherits@2.0.1, string_decoder@0.10.31, core-util-is@1.0.2)        
remote: └── mongodb-core@1.3.1 (require_optional@1.0.0, bson@0.4.21)        
remote: 
remote: bwip-js@0.15.1 node_modules/bwip-js        
remote: npm info ok         
remote: Preparing build for deployment        
remote: Deployment id is a123e49b        
remote: Activating deployment        
remote: Starting MongoDB cartridge        
remote: Waiting for mongo to start...        
remote: Starting NodeJS cartridge        
remote: Thu Feb 11 2016 23:28:33 GMT-0500 (EST): Starting application 'pontotec' ...        
remote: Waiting for application port (8080) become available ...        
remote: Application 'pontotec' failed to start (port 8080 not available)        
remote: -------------------------        
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: failure        
remote: Activation status: failure        
remote: Activation failed for the following gears:        
remote: 56bc23fd0c1e667ea00000e3 (Error activating gear: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control start' for /var/lib/openshift/56bc23fd0c1e667ea00000e3/nodejs        
remote: #<IO:0x000000020df3c0>        
remote: #<IO:0x000000020df348>        
remote: )        
remote: Deployment completed with status: failure        
remote: postreceive failed        
To ssh://56bc23fd0c1e667ea00000e3@pontotec-smallservices.rhcloud.com/~/git/pontotec.git/
 = [up to date]      v0.3.0 -> v0.3.0
 = [up to date]      v0.3.1 -> v0.3.1
 = [up to date]      v0.3.2 -> v0.3.2
 = [up to date]      v0.3.3 -> v0.3.3
 = [up to date]      v0.4.0 -> v0.4.0
 = [up to date]      v0.4.0_openshift -> v0.4.0_openshift
   a662d84..e7b5753  master -> master
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master'
Completed successfully
```

Ele diz que "Completed successfully", mas quando tento acessar meu aplicativo remoto eu recebo erro 503.

Meu `server.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();





app.set("nodeIP", process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1")
app.set("nodePORT", process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || "3000")





app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(bodyParser({limit: '50mb'}));







var routerOs = express.Router();

// puts
routerOs.post('/puts/putServico', require('./routes/os/puts/putServico.js')); // ok
// deletes
routerOs.post('/deletes/deleteServico', require('./routes/os/deletes/deleteServico.js')) // ok

// gets
routerOs.get('/gets/getServico', require('./routes/os/gets/getServico.js'));
routerOs.get('/gets/getServicosList', require('./routes/os/gets/getServicosList.js'))

routerOs.get('/gets/verifyClientIncidence', require('./routes/os/gets/verifyClientIncidence.js'))
// updates
routerOs.post('/updates/updateServico', require('./routes/os/updates/updateServico.js')); // ok



app.use('/os', routerOs);













var routerOthers = express.Router();

routerOthers.get('/gets/getBarCodeImg', require('./routes/others/gets/getBarCodeImg.js'))
//routerStaff.post('/sendServicoNotification', require('./server/others/posts/sendServicoNotification.js'))

app.use('/others', routerOthers)








app.listen(app.get("nodePORT"), function(err) {
  console.log('server ligado');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.set("IP", process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1");
app.set("PORT", process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || "3000");
```